# ExactTarget Fuel API for Core Account

Tags: marketing-cloud, licenses, fuel-sdk

Can someone confirm that the MessageDefinitionSends service (Fuel API) works with Core account types?  I noticed that this does not work with Enterprise 1.0 account types.

Answer (score 1):

This API is available with the Interaction of User-Initiated Email Sending, which is available in the Advanced, Enterprise and Enterprise 2.0 edition.

It will not work on the Core account, although I think you can add Interactions to a core account (but it's not the norm).